# Spring Security allowing unauthorized access to secured method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add security to my web application using Spring MVC, REST controllers and Spring Data.
The issue I am encountering is that the methods annotated with @PreAuthorized are accessible to anyone (no login is required).

**My Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/public/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String storeEntityPublic(@PathVariable String name) {
    String result = "Hello " + name + ", I am saving on the db. (PUBLIC)";
    /* stuff */ 

    return result;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String storeEntityUserOrAdmin(@PathVariable String name) {
    String result = "Hello " + name
            + ", I am saving on the db. (USER OR ADMIN)";
    controller.saveEntity(name);

    return result;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String storeEntityAdmin(@PathVariable String name) {
    String result = "Hello Admin " + name
        + ", I am saving on the db. (ADMIN ONLY)";
    controller.saveEntity(name);

    return result;
}
}
```

**My security config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config="true" />

<!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

My applicationContext correctly import the security configuration file.

In my web.xml, I added the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Finally, **my applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:spring/*.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.my.project" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-security.xml" />
</beans>
```

The project is correctly deployed and I have no warnings concerning security.

Comment: May be delete the cookies in the browser and try again.

Comment: that's not a solution unfortunately, I test in incognito mode.

Comment: Try to add <intercept-url in the spring-security-config.xml with the <http element.

Comment: That works, yes, but I need to use the annotation-based mode.

Comment: Configure intercept urls using annotations? then use @ Configuration on a custom config class to configure. I guess, @ preauth is different than the configuration, @ PreAuth is a method level security, i.e., you are narrowing the security per level.

Comment: Not sure I got your comment.What I would like to do is to avoid specifying the security levels required to access a particular REST service via XML. Therefore, I tried the @PreAuthorize annotation to narrow down the access permissions to each single request by-passing the intercepts in the XML. This way, I thought I could drop every intercept directive from the XML and just realy on method annotations. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Add `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />` to the context file loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. AOP will only be applied to beans in the same context, you probably have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` both loading (hopefully) different sets of beans and the security is being loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` effectivly not affecting beans loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security documentation says on annotated methods:

> The annotated methods will only be secured for instances which are defined as Spring beans (in the same application context in which method-security is enabled).

I suppose that you define your controller beans in different context than you define your security context. Try to put the below element into context defining beans to be secured.

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Comment: I am not sure where to add that element: I already have it in applicationContext-security xml. I posted also my applicationContext.xml. Where should I add the global-method-security element?

Comment: Try to add it into your applicationContext.xml.

Comment: When I add it to the applicationContext.xml and comment the intercepts, I can freely access all pages and methods, including the ones that should not be accessed.

Comment: Strange, everything seems to be OK. Try to add `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />` into applicationContext.xml since your controllers do no implement any interface.